# Equality of partial derivatives (Schwartz’s theorem) and total differential

Tags: physical-chemistry

I'm reviewing some Physical Chemistry concepts and the two books I'm using show the total differential and right away they present the Schwartz's theorem. I don't get the relationship. In the screenshot below you can see that the author mentions that the mixed partial second derivatives can be obtained from the total differential. What is the relationship between equations like 1.7 and 1.8, in general?

I got the screenshot from this excellent book: https://peverati.github.io/pchem1/SystemVariables.html#thermodynamic-variables

Atkins does the same think on Mathematical Background 2, pg 91, ninth edition.

[image]

Comment: There is no real "direct" connection between 1.7 and 1.8. Equations 1.8 are manifestation of the [Schwartz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives), which states that you can (if the function is "well-behaved") change the order of differentiation. That means that given the function $f(x,y)$, the second derivatives are the same: $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)$. In the equation 1.8, this equality is then used for the function $P(T,V)$.

Comment: I thought there was a connection because of this statement "the mixed partial second derivatives that can be obtained from eq. (1.7) are the same"
On Atkins is similar " The quantity df is also called the differential of f. Successive partial derivatives may be taken in any order:"

Comment: I read the surrounding context and I don't see the connection myself - I think if you understand 1.7 and 1.8 separately you're doing fine.